# access interface out of the class java

Tags: java, interface

I have a class `A`, another is `B`, there is one interface `Ai` with one method `ok()` only.

Class A implements Ai, inside the ok I'm printing just a line.

**Class B has an instance of A, I want to access A's interface Ai inside B.**

*Can it be done ? If so how ?*

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        new B();
     }
}

class A implements Ai{
    
    public A(){
        ok();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void ok(){
        System.out.println("ok???");
    }
}

class B{
    public B(){
        A a = new A();
        // I want to call interface of A from here,
        // so I can get the exact ok method of A
        // that print's "ok???" from inside class B
    }
}

interface Ai{
    public void ok();
}
```

Comment: You can just call the method `a.ok();`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.

Comment: Agreed with @Jesper

Comment: @Jesper what if `ok` has parameter ?

Comment: @Danial just the same way you pass the parameter to `System.out.println`

Comment: There's nothing special here, it's just calling a method, if it has a parameter, you pass the parameter: `a.ok(1, 2, "whatever");`. Tutorial: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A implements So{
 B b;
 @Override
 so(int x){
   if(b!==null){
     b.so(x);
   }
 }
}
class B implements So{
 A a;
 @Override
 so(int x){
   if(a!==null){
     a.so(x);
   }
 }
}
```

All I needed is this. Have query? Comment please.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        new B();
     }
}

class A implements Ai{
    
    public A(){
        ok();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void ok(){
        System.out.println("ok???");
    }
}

class B{
    public B(){
        A a = new A();
        //just call a.ok() here to execute A implementation of Ai.ok()
        a.ok(); // <--- 
    }
}

interface Ai{
    public void ok();
}
```

Comment: what if `ok` has parameter ?

Comment: you have to pass that parameters to B's constructor and call a.ok() with parameters